# what is the best products sort option on e-commerce website?

Tags: user-behavior, user-expectation, e-commerce, users

I am trying to add a new products types collection on my website after I added a collection the first page of Pet Shop Collection will only contain one type (last type have been added) like the following:
[image]

Do I need to re-order it manually and put one product for each type, if i need to do that, that will need a lot of effort to sort all collection manually like the following, what did you think it is better for user?
[image]

Comment: To clarify - are you asking if the images shown by default need to represent one of each category in order of the category listing displayed on the left?

Comment: actually, I am trying to know if i need to show images from all types on the home page of collection as image #2, is that more useful for customer?

Comment: Then I support @Danielillo's answer - you can use the default images to push products that are most important for the business to sell. They don't need to tie to the categories. Users use category filters to find something they already want vs. understanding everything that a business sells.

Answer (score 2):

If the online store already has a side column with filters so the user can immediately search for the product they are looking for, I don't think it's necessary to show one of each type.

An online store should have the same philosophy as a real one and the main page is the sales showcase. If it's a supermarket, instead of placing each type of product that it sells, it would put the best sale options and suggestions.

A good marketing plan would say that it's perhaps more important to show products by type of sale, such as "best sellers", "featured offers", "latest news" ...

I would implement a *recommended* list of products in addition to the filter.

[image: sort by]

<sub>*Example store: [levi.com](https://www.levi.com/GB/en_GB/promo/c/levi_men_promo_north)*</sub>